# Raw ECG signals from QardioCore via bluetooth (Android)

Tags: android, bluetooth, signals, wearables, heartrate

Is it possible to retrieve raw ECG signals programmatically from QardioCore via bluetooth?
I only have an Android device, and as the Android Qardio app doesn't work for QardioCore, I wanted to know if anyone already tried to write an own app for usage with Android, and if it worked?

Comment: looks like they dont have api's exposed for other 3rd party apps to use the device data , i dont see any developer sdk as well , contact them for a sdk or a lib which will expose the data , other than this i dont see any other way

Comment: You can try to listen to the generic characteristic Heart Rate from the Bluetooth Specification to get the computed ECG from the QardioCore. Apps like nRf Connect can be useful to identify what's possible with your  Qardio Core over Bluetooth. If you're looking for the raw ECG signal, your should consired sending a mail to Qardio to request them a SDK as @VinaySasalatti says.

Comment: @RxVincent With a connected and bonded QardioCore, nRf Connect does not show any ECG stream, but a bunch of other not relevant information. However, with other devices, e.g., heart rate wearables, it works fine. So now we aim at spoofing our OS as iOS when connecting to the QardioCore, let's see how that goes.

Comment: @KevinSP - Have you had any luck with this? I am thinking of getting a cheap iOS device to start reverse-engineering the BLE protocol.

If you are still interested, I would love to team up on this.

Answer (score 3):

The manufacturer wrote me in an email:

> Qardio Core will be compatible with iOS only and we are focused on providing
>   a smooth experience on Apple devices that use iOS 10.0 or later.
>
> [...] there are no immediate plans to bring QardioCore to the Android
>   platform [...]

This apparently means that there are no SDKs as well.

Comment: This is so sad... :(

Answer (score 0):

I have also emailed the manufacturer and got a similar answer:

> [...]
>   Qardio Core will only be compatible with iOS for the foreseeable
>   future. We strive to provide the best experience and have not been
>   able to guarantee flawless operation on the multitude of Android
>   devices.
>
> An SDK is also not available at this time.
>   [...]